# Django searching for a particular record

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

Im trying to search for a particular record, based on the ID i have input into the button on the UI:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-icon-only btn-outline-primary" type="button" value={{ skill.id }} name='editbut'>
```

I have checked and the ID reflects correctly

In the view, I have the below. This works when I hardcode in the value, but when I try to extract it from the button value, it fails.

Any help would be amazing!!

Thanks

```
def edit_skill(request):
    skillid = request.POST.get('editbut')
    t = skills.objects.get(id=skillid)  
    t.status = 'closed'
    t.save() # this will update only
    messages.success(request, ('Changes saved'))

    return redirect('index')
```

Comment: Is the surrounding `<form>` a POST form?

Comment: The `value` of a button whose type is button is _not_ posted (the value of `submit` buttons are posted only in case they caused the submit). You want a _hidden field_ to have the value instead.